# Displaying user information on Google Map on click of the location using node js, express and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-maps, express, mongoose

I am doing a small project which takes user information like name, age, location etc and display it on the Google map on click of that location.

I have completed the first part i.e., taking user information using node js, express and Mongo db.

I am not understanding how to go to next part and display that information on Google maps on click of that location.

Any tutorial or pointers would be helpful on how to go forward. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to display markers on webpage you might want to check google documentation:

- To create a marker on map documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple), also if you
  want to add a custom marker image sample is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple).
- To display the information on the google maps on marker sample
  [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple).

I'm assuming you are storing the marker information in your DB, so you can retrieve it from there, just create a schema for **marker** and **markerinfo**.

Way to add a marker to map with onClick event:

```
map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
});

function placeMarker(position, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position, // {lat: -100.000, lng: 100.000};
        map: map
    });
    map.panTo(position);
}
```

Getting marker from express api with jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("/api/marker/1", function(json) {

placeMarker(json,map);

});
```

Ping me if you have questions;

Good luck;

Comment: Thanks for the information sBanda. I'm new to Node JS. Yes. I'm storing information in MongoDB and have created schema for it. I'm able to access maps using the information from Google maps api. Can you please explain how to show them on maps from mongodb?

Comment: Depends on the technology you chose for the UI.